# Interested in a good intelligent search module

Tags: search, ee-1.14.2.0

The only one i keep seeing is by "klevu"... does anyone have any opinions on klevu and or what other options are out there.

Looking for better (than native) search functionality and maybe some good intelligent searching with images.

Comment: i refer this : https://mirasvit.com/magento-extensions/sphinx-search-ultimate.html?utm_source=magento-connect&utm_medium=product-page&utm_campaign=SSU

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend an intelligent search solution like Solr or Elasticsearch. Look at IntegerNet_Solr for a Solr integration maybe. But be careful - beside of the Magento Extensions you need and have to manage an dedicated Solr Server.